# Chef, ruby hashes and templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra

I know this is more a `ruby` question than `chef`, but...

I have some attributes like:

```
default['my_cookbook']['some_namespace1']['some_attribute1'] = 'some_value1'
default['my_cookbook']['some_namespace1']['some_attribute2'] = 'some_value2'
default['my_cookbook']['some_namespace1']['some_attribute2'] = 'some_value3'
...
default['my_cookbook']['some_namespace2']['some_attribute1'] = 'some_value1'
default['my_cookbook']['some_namespace2']['some_attribute2'] = 'some_value2'
default['my_cookbook']['some_namespace2']['some_attribute2'] = 'some_value3'
...
```

On the other hand, I am creating a template resource like this:

```
template 'template_name' do
  source 'template_source.erb'
  variables (
    my_namespace_1: node['my_cookbook']['some_namespace1'],
    my_namespace_2: node['my_cookbook']['some_namespace2']
  )
end
```

Then in the `template_source.erb` I try:

```
...
<%= @my_namespace_1['some_attribute1'] %> #=> 'some_value1'
...
```

However when I run Kitchen I get this, instead of `'some_value1'`:

```
Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError
------------------------------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

How should I send the template variable to use it this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: This applies only to Ruby in general and not to Chef in particular.

Pass a nested hash:

```
template 'template_name' do
  source 'template_source.erb'
  variables (
    my_namespace_1: {
      some_attribute1: node['my_cookbook']['some_namespace1']['some_attribute1']
    }
  )
end
```

But rather than copying the values verbatim you can use the full power of the [Hash class](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html) to slice, dice and merge together whatever you want:

```
template 'template_name' do
  source 'template_source.erb'
  variables (
    node['my_cookbook'].slice('some_namespace1', 'some_namespace2')
  )
end
```

One gotcha in Ruby that you have tripped on is that symbols are usually used as hash keys:

```
# newer literal syntax
a_hash = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

# or with the older hash-rocket syntax
a_hash = {
  :foo => 'bar'
}
```

Symbols are extemly efficient since they are interned strings that are stored in table - when comparing symbols you compare the object ID instead of comparing each character in the string.

In fact strings are only really used when you want keys in the hash that are not valid Ruby symbols - like when building a hash of HTTP headers.

Ruby does not treat symbol and string keys indifferently:

```
{
  foo: 'bar'
}[:foo] 
# => bar

{
  foo: 'bar'
}['foo'] 
# => nil
```

So to access the passed variable in the template you would use:

```
<%= @my_namespace_1[:some_attribute1] %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information!

Just the nested hash did the trick, but is good to know all the other information.

Comment: Chef might use `HashWithIndifferentAccess` from ActiveSupport (Rails) which is a subclass of hash that treats string and symbol keys alike. Otherwise you would get nil if it was just a vanilla Ruby hash.

Comment: We don't use that, but we have something similar.

Comment: In fact this whole answer is basically incorrect in the context of Chef.

Comment: We do not recommend the use of symbol keys in node attributes, and passing partial attribute trees in to a template is 100% okay.

Comment: @coderanger I fully agree with your edit, I was answering from a pure ruby standpoint. I would delete it if it was not accepted which locks it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the example should be working. I am guessing you have a typo somewhere in your original recipe that you corrected when generic-ifying the code.